# Select2 4.0 - Keypress does not trigger selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2-4, jquery-select2-3

I've upgraded `Select2` from version `3.5.2` to version `4.0.`

We have plenty of forms with many fields filled in by typists.

In the old version (`3.5.2`) the typists would use the following sequence:

1. Focus on the element
2. Type a number
3. Press `Tab` to both select the result and move on to the next field

```js
$("select").select2();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/3.5.2/select2.min.js"></script>

<style>
  input {
  display:block;
    margin:10px 0;
  }
</style>

<input type=text/>
<select>
  <option value="1">1. Option A</option>
  <option value="2">2. Option B</option>
  <option value="3">3. Option C</option>
  <option value="4">4. Option D</option>
  <option value="5">5. Option E</option>
</select>

<input type=text/>
```

On version `4.0` the typists must:

1. Focus on the element
2. Hit `Enter`
3. Type the number
4. Press `Enter` again
5. Press tab to blur and move to the next field

```js
$("select").select2();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>

<style>
  input {
    display:block;
    margin:10px 0;
  }  
  
</style>

<input type=text/>

<select>
  <option value="1">1. Option A</option>
  <option value="2">2. Option B</option>
  <option value="3">3. Option C</option>
  <option value="4">4. Option D</option>
  <option value="5">5. Option E</option>
</select>

<input type=text/>
```

Is there a way around this apparent downgrade in functionality?
I don't want to resort to `v3.5.2` because I'm using AJAX on `<select>` elements which is not supported in this version (one must use hidden `<input>` tag instead)

Comment: In Select2 3.5.2 this option was called selectOnBlur, I think this has been renamed to SelectOnClose, have a look at the "Options" page on the Select2 homepage.

Comment: Thanks. This seems to require an adapter and a decorator. Couldn't figure out from the docs how this is done. Would appreciate an example. Also, this seems to remove step 4, but not step 2.

Answer (score 1):

To trigger the opening of select2 on focus use jQuery's native "focus" event & select2 "open" event. **Important:** Make it on DOM is ready.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
  $(".select2-selection").on("focus", function () { 
      $(this).parent().parent().prev().select2("open"); 
  });
   
});
```